# Youtube Api LiveChatMessages: insert

Tags: oauth, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to create a bot that moderates youtube channels, but your api doesn't allow you to use the apiKey to use this api resource.

What alternatives do I have? Is there any other solution to use this api resource without doing an oauth2? or is there any way to do oauth2 from the api without going through a browser to get a valid token and use the api?

Thanks

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to create a bot that moderates youtube channels, but your api doesn't allow you to use the apiKey to use this api resource.

Api keys are only useable for public data not private user data

> Is there any other solution to use this api resource without doing an oauth2?

You need to use Oauth2 and request authorization of the owner of the data.

> is there any way to do oauth2 from the api without going through a browser to get a valid token and use the api?

No the user will always need to open the consent screen in a browser window.  this will return to you the access token you need to access private user data.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer!

I am currently trying to use a google Service Account, to access and manipulate the youtube api.

All Get requests work without problems and return results. But when I try to do an insert the api gives me this error


`{"error": {
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.api.v3.LiveChatMessageInsertResponse.Error",
    "reason": "ERROR_UNSPECIFIED"
   }
  ],
  "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
 }
}`
The payload is trhe same that api example youtube (here works with own token)

Comment: The youtube api doesn't support service accounts unless its via domain wide delegation to a google workspace domain.